# Same packages in `main` and `test` are treated as if they were different

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, kotlin, access-modifiers

So I have a project where all the packages `com.foo.etc` in `src/main` are treated as if they were different from the identically named package in `src/test`.

That is very annoying because it means I cannot test `protected` methods and I have to specify the `classes` in my `@SpringBootTest` annotations.

What are common causes for this?

Comment: Are the directory names exactly the same in both places - including case?

Comment: @user944849 Yes.

Comment: If you like to test package private etc. you have to have the same packages in `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` which is the usual case to make such things possible... Apart from that I would think about testing a protected method..that sounds like a smell...

Comment: @khmarbaise I am well aware, thank you. And in other projects, it's working perfectly fine. I'm trying to figure out why it isn't in this one. As for testing protected methods, it's an override of a library method that needs testing.

Comment: So you have overwritten a protected method of a class which is inherited? A code example would help here a lot...

Comment: @khmarbaise no, it wouldn't since the problem is not inherit to THAT method alone. (Otherwise it would find the spring application class, which it doesn't.) ALL packages are affected.

Comment: Full example project which reproduces the behaviour...